# Using .htaccess to redirect to https, subfolder and prevent naked domain URLs?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm having a heck of a time constructing an .htaccess file to do everything that I need. I have a domain that is only hosting a forum in a /forums subdirectory.  I have no landing page, nor do I intend to.

So I want to redirect the root domain to the /forums subfolder, force https and THEN PREVENT naked domains from being allowed.

I've got it all working except users can still manually access/choose a naked domain variant. Some users have been bookmarking the naked domain variant and I want to force them, and all users, back into the www. prefix.

The code below takes http:[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or http:example.com and forces it to https://www.example.com/forums/.  The problem is users are still able to manually access https://example.com/forums.

I've tried a bunch of different things to force the forums in the /forums subdirectory to always use a www. prefix, but nothing has worked thus far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/forums [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples/attempts could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
##Handle non https all urls here.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [NE,R=301,L]

##Handle non www urls here.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

##Handle no uri link with no www page.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/forums [R=301,L]

##Handle no uri link with www page.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works to force http to https and it solves my issue with forcing the www. prefix in the subdirectory.  However, it creates a redirect loop when visiting the root domain www.example.com  with "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: @spaceman-spiff, ok by which file in backend you want to serve your root URL?

Comment: I'm running a forum located at `https://www.example.com/forums/` and I'm trying to make everything re-direct there with a www. prefix and forcing https